# jQuery looping through ajax json response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, response, each

I have a JSON response from PHP like this:

```
[[{"name":"J1","id":"0088","order":"2928868"}],[{"name":"J2","id":"0171","order":"2928868"}],[{"name":"J2","id":"0249","order":"2928868"}]]
```

What I want to do with this is out output the order number which is always the same in an element with an id of #ordernum.

Then for the other parts, i want to create a couple of divs within a container div for the name and id.

I'm pretty sure I can get that bit working but what i'm unsure of is how to loop through each of the JSON rows to get to the part where i can create my divs

This is what I have so far but this appends to a div where i want to create new divs.

Would i need to do another $.each() after $('#ordernum').text(row[0].order);?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "check.php",
    data: { order: order },
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {

        if(response.length != 0) {
            console.log(response.order);
            $.each(response, function(index, row) {

                console.log(row);
                $('#ordernum').text(row[0].order);

                $('.name').append(row[0].name+"<br />");
                $('.id').append(row[0].id+"<br />");
            });
        }
        else {
            $('#foo').text('Order number not found!!');
        }

        // set the focus to the order input
        $('#order').focus().val('');
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('An Ajax error was thrown.');
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

This is how the json is created.  $rows is from a query from a SQLSERVER database and I loop through that to get all the rows from the MySQL database

```
foreach($rows as $row) {

    $sql = 'SELECT bin, id FROM totebin WHERE id= :id';

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':tote', trim($row['id']));
    $stmt->execute();

    $array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $array[0]['id'] = str_pad($array[0]['id'], 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $array[0]['order'] = trim($row['order']);

    $output[] = $array;
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Try `var response = JSON.parse(response);` within success handler.

Comment: why do you have an array of arrays

Comment: the response can be reformatted to `[{"name":"J1","id":"0088","order":"2928868"},{"name":"J2","id":"0171","order":"2928868"},{"name":"J2","id":"0249","order":"2928868"}]`

Comment: try using  $('#ordernum').text(row.order); into the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think everthing is working right
just **response.order** will say undefined.

if .each loop is not working as saying then put before loop
    var response = $.parseJSON(response).

and if u need resopnse like

```
[{"name":"J1","id":"0088","order":"2928868"},{"name":"J2","id":"0171","order":"‌​2928868"},{"name":"J2","id":"0249","order":"2928868"}]
```

then in php code you can do in second last line

```
 $output[] = $array[0];
```

then you will not need index in javascript.

```
 $('#ordernum').text(row[0].order);
```

put this code in fire bug console.

```
var response =[[{"name":"J1","id":"0088","order":"2928868"}],[{"name":"J2","id":"0171","order":"2928868"}],[{"name":"J2","id":"0249","order":"2928868"}]];

console.log(response.length);
console.log(response.order);
$.each(response, function(index, row) {

         console.log(row[0].name);     
         });
```

and check the result

and you can create your div under first loop, you do not need second like even you do not change your response, or you reformat that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I've done the php side with the json response and get what you get but i get this error now SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character when using var response = $.parseJSON(response) and using your .each.  Would it be possible to put it in a fiddle so i can see it working?

Comment: you can first check you valid json on json.parser.online.fr. fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g2S9L/2/